# PhpMyAdmin data in a text file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin for my data. 
I would like to have the data on a text file, that I need to process with matab afterwards. But phpMyAdmin doesn't offer this possibility, I know I can export my table in many formats like CSV or PDF, but they all don't seem convenient for what I need...
It seems like I will have to export the data in one of those formats and then write a program that will put the data on the text file...
But my question is : which format is the more convenient for this kind of processing ?
I already thought of PHP array but I am not using Web for that...
What do you think ?

Comment: What do you mean by text file? A csv is a text file. Or do you mean xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export your table to a csv file, then import the file to MATLAB. Matlab has commands to import csv files,check out this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html).
Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043721/fastest-way-to-import-csv-files-in-matlab), if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Save as data.csv, then rename the file to data.txt.  Simple as that.